# Short story about a bureaucracy becoming (extremely) over-efficient

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

I remember what I believe is a short story, possibly by Isaac Asimov, where in a not-so-strange human (?) civilization bureaucracy suddenly goes over efficient at performing its duties. This results in a Kafkaesque nightmarish life for all citizens who face constant harassment, something which is not too far from what many of us experience in modern all-connected world.

E.g., they suddenly receive unwanted benefits which get removed in the following day (early in story) or hour (later), if I remember correctly. It seems to me the pace of that all was going exponentially, but the end was rather an anti-climactic one, where everything returns to the "normal" state of things of not being able to get things done from administrations.

I believe this was in the style of Asimov's short stories, it could be Ray Bradbury or even French writer Marcel Aymé though. I've read it in the 90s, but I'd say it was written long before that, in the 1920s-60s range.

Comment: How does being over efficient become nightmarish? Do people have to sign hundreds of pages of forms for trivial things? Their lives are already predetermined by an AI who had it all worked out?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Rather the former. They also receive a lot of unwanted benefits which get removed in the following day (early in story) or hour (later), if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details to [edit] into your question.  For example, when did you read this?

Comment: Adding and then removing an unwanted benefit does not sound efficient. It sounds like busy work. Interesting plot though.

Comment: @Jontia Agreed - say overly efficient in *processing* things, and making contradictory decisions. Not 100% certain of all these details I add though, that's more to give some idea of the "spirit" of the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frank Herbert's *The Tactful Saboteur* (Galaxy, Oct. 1964)

The hero, Jorj X. McKie works for an interstellar government agency (the Bureau of Sabotage) dedicated to slowing down a too-efficient bureaucracy. Herbert's galactic ConSentiency universe was later expanded with the novels *Whipping Star* and *The Dosadi Experiment*

Comment: That's it! I hadn't thought of Herbert for this, but indeed it is also in his range. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'll have to re-read it, but as I recall the Saboteur slowed down the Law Makers to keep them from passing laws without proper thought.  I also don't recall the efficiency of government affecting the population.